# jQuery show/hide div in body from inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have a fairly simple question (about those damn selectors!) regarding jQuery. I have 2 div's in my body that I had when the site loads. But I want them to show when a certain image is clicked. The problem is that the image is inside a few other elements (div's, ul, li).

I made this simple fiddle to show the div structure http://jsfiddle.net/MspYV/ . So the question is, how do I reach the div's #change_settings_container and .change_settings_translucent from a totally other div/element?

Comment: could you post the html markup on here in your question? jsfiddle is not running well for me today :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the div's `#change_settings_container` it's as simple as `$("#change_settings_container")`

Comment: Hey Jospeh, what does the $ sign stand for? A selector for the body?

Comment: @Peter Boomsma `$(something-in-here)` is how jQuery selects elements.  What we are using here is an id selector `$("#id-of-attribute")`. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).  You may be using the jQuery version of that such as `jQuery("#change_settings_container")`, but they work the same (the latter is a no-conflict mode version).

Comment: hey that was a stupid remark of me, I knew that. But the problem is how can I select a div that's in the body? I'll read a bit on the link you gave (ps, how can you post code comments?)

Comment: @Peter Boomsma code comments are done by either enclosing the code in the ` character or by indenting the text by 4 spaces (this way can only be done in questions and answers, though).  The easiest way is to just highlight the text and click the `{}` button.  Also, it seems your code does work.  It just needs to use `$` instead of `jQuery`. http://jsfiddle.net/MspYV/1/

Comment: yea the code of hiding the div works fine, but I can't figure out how to show the div. 

`jQuery("#change_settings_container, .change_settings_translucent").hide()   
 jQuery("#first_view_close span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
 $("body > #change_settings_translucent").fadeToggle(200);     
});`

I thought something like this, where the body is the selector, but ofcourse it didn't work.

Comment: huh?! how weird... so I was thinking completely wrong? Doesn't jQuery need a selector, can it just pick the div through the html? You blew my mind sir. And yes, that's excactly what I needed. I really need to get a good book about jQuery.

Comment: @Peter Boomsma yup :) jQuery can arbitrarily grab an id out of anywhere on the page (because id's are unique) or one or more elements with a given class.  With classes, however, you may want to limit it.  For instance if you have a div with a class of "child" in a div with an id of "parent", you can use `$(#parent .child)` and it doesn't even matter how deep the child is embedded.  what jQuery uses are css selectors.  You can find a [list of them here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.change_settings_close_button img").click(function(){
    $('div.change_settings_translucent').hide();
});

$("span.toggle").click(function(){
    $('div.change_settings_translucent, div#change_settings_container').toggle();
});
```

See an example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/K2znp/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/K2znp/3/)

Comment: Hey ExpertCode, it's not so much about selecting the image but how to have a click on that image close a div that's in the body and not in the same div structure as the image.

Comment: hey thanks, that's the idear but the problem is that jQuery can't find the div that it needs to hide since they are in complete different div's.

Comment: But when the image is clicked, which 'div' you want to hide?

Comment: aah I see, yea maybe I wasn't clear enough but the party you have I allready had. Could you check this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/K2znp/1/ I want to close the div's using the span with the class toggle...

Comment: It's this what you want: [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/K2znp/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/K2znp/3/)

Comment: It is! It's the same code as Joseph fixed, I was just under the assumption that jQuery needed a selector... but all fixed now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".small-image img").click(function () {
            $(".main-image img").hide();
            $(".small-image img").show();
            var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
            $(".main-image").addClass("img");
            $(".img").css('background-image', 'url(' + imgsrc + ')');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would you like to add an explanation to your answer? As it stands its not clear why this answer should stand out